# Presenting from swapchain induces segfault

Tags: c, vulkan

Currently trying to create a main loop which presents images from a swapchain:

```
void loop(struct Context *ctx, void(*loopfn)(struct Context*)) {
    VkQueue queue;
    vkGetDeviceQueue(ctx->objects.device, 0, 0, &queue);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(ctx->window)) {
        VkResult fenceStatus = vkGetFenceStatus(ctx->objects.device, ctx->objects.fence);

        if (fenceStatus == VK_SUCCESS) {
            // Reset fence and command buffer

            if (vkQueuePresentKHR(queue, &ctx->objects.presentInfo) != VK_SUCCESS) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to present image\n");
                break;
            }

            loopfn(ctx);
        } else if (fenceStatus == VK_ERROR_DEVICE_LOST) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Device lost\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}

void loopfn(struct Context *ctx) {
    // Clear color image
}

int main() {
    struct Context *ctx = init(500, 500, "Test");
    if (!ctx)
        return -1;

    loop(ctx, loopfn);

    deinit(ctx);
    return 0;
}
```

However, it looks like I'm using the swapchain extension in an incorrect way, which translates to the following error message from the validation layers, immediately followed by a segmentation fault:

```
UNASSIGNED-CoreValidation-DrawState-SwapchainInvalidImage(ERROR / SPEC): msgNum: 0 - vkQueuePresentKHR: Swapchain image index too large (0). There are only 0 images in this swapchain.
    Objects: 1
       [0] 0x7, type: 1000001000, name: (null)
Validation(ERROR): msg_code: 0:  [ UNASSIGNED-CoreValidation-DrawState-SwapchainInvalidImage ] Object: 0x7 (Type = 27) | vkQueuePresentKHR: Swapchain image index too large (0). There are only 0 images in this swapchain.
```

My `init` function is very long and I don't know if it'd be very useful to put it in here, but what I'm essentially doing (and which does not work) is:

- Creating the swapchain as follows:

  ```
  VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR swapchainInfo =
      { .sType                 = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SWAPCHAIN_CREATE_INFO_KHR
      , .pNext                 = NULL
      , .flags                 = 0x00000000
      , .surface               = ctx->objects.surface
      , .minImageCount         = surfaceCapabilities.minImageCount
      , .imageFormat           = pSurfaceFormats[0].format
      , .imageColorSpace       = pSurfaceFormats[0].colorSpace
      , .imageExtent           = surfaceCapabilities.currentExtent
      , .imageArrayLayers      = 1
      , .imageUsage            = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT
      , .imageSharingMode      = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE
      , .queueFamilyIndexCount = 1
      , .pQueueFamilyIndices   = NULL
      , .preTransform          = VK_SURFACE_TRANSFORM_IDENTITY_BIT_KHR
      , .compositeAlpha        = VK_COMPOSITE_ALPHA_OPAQUE_BIT_KHR
      , .presentMode           = VK_PRESENT_MODE_MAILBOX_KHR
      , .clipped               = VK_TRUE
      , .oldSwapchain          = VK_NULL_HANDLE
      };

  if (vkCreateSwapchainKHR(ctx->objects.device, &swapchainInfo, NULL, &ctx->objects.swapchain) != VK_SUCCESS)
      goto failure;
  ```
- Creating the color image and depth image. Both `VkImageCreateInfo` structures have a pointer to the following struct as their `pNext` value:

  ```
  VkImageSwapchainCreateInfoKHR swapchainImageInfo =
      { .sType     = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_SWAPCHAIN_CREATE_INFO_KHR
      , .pNext     = NULL
      , .swapchain = ctx->objects.swapchain
      };
  ```
- Allocating memory for both images, then attempting to bind them to the swapchain as follows:

  ```
  VkBindImageMemorySwapchainInfoKHR colorSwapchainBindInfo =
      { .sType      = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_BIND_IMAGE_MEMORY_SWAPCHAIN_INFO_KHR
      , .pNext      = NULL
      , .swapchain  = ctx->objects.swapchain
      , .imageIndex = 0
      };

  VkBindImageMemoryInfo colorMemBindInfo =
      { .sType        = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_BIND_IMAGE_MEMORY_INFO
      , .pNext        = &colorSwapchainBindInfo
      , .image        = ctx->objects.colorImage
      , .memory       = ctx->objects.colorMemory
      , .memoryOffset = 0
      };

  // Pretty much the same thing for the depth image

  VkBindImageMemoryInfo memBindInfos[] = { colorMemBindInfo, depthMemBindInfo };

  if (vkBindImageMemory2(ctx->objects.device, 2, memBindInfos) != VK_SUCCESS)
      goto failure;
  ```
- Performing the two needed image layout transitions (from `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED` to `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL`)
- Creating the two needed image views, a framebuffer and a `VkPresentInfoKHR` struct

I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it. Feel free to ask for any additional precisions.

**Edit:** The instance extensions I'm using are `VK_KHR_surface` and `VK_KHR_xcb_surface`.

```
uint32_t count;
const char **extensions = glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions(&count);

VkInstanceCreateInfo instanceInfo =
    { .sType                   = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO
    , .pNext                   = NULL
    , .flags                   = 0x00000000
    , .pApplicationInfo        = NULL
    , .enabledLayerCount       = 0
    , .ppEnabledLayerNames     = NULL
    , .enabledExtensionCount   = count
    , .ppEnabledExtensionNames = extensions
    };
```

The only device extension I'm using is `VK_KHR_swapchain`:

```
const char *deviceExtensions[] = { "VK_KHR_swapchain" };

VkDeviceCreateInfo deviceInfo =
    { .sType                   = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_CREATE_INFO
    , .pNext                   = NULL
    , .flags                   = 0x00000000
    , .queueCreateInfoCount    = 1
    , .pQueueCreateInfos       = &queueInfo
    , .enabledLayerCount       = 0
    , .ppEnabledLayerNames     = NULL
    , .enabledExtensionCount   = sizeof(deviceExtensions) / sizeof(deviceExtensions[0])
    , .ppEnabledExtensionNames = deviceExtensions
    , .pEnabledFeatures        = NULL
    };
```

Comment: What extensions do You use and how do You enable them? Any Validation Layers warnings or errors?

Comment: You should probably be calling `vkGetSwapchainImagesKHR` to obtain the image count. Also the `memory` member should be `VK_NULL_HANDLE` when using `VkBindImageMemorySwapchainInfoKHR`. Also swapchain AFAIK does not have depth even with this extension you are using, so that does not make sense to me.

Comment: @Ekzuzy I edited my message so you can see how I'm enabling the extensions I need. I'm not getting any warning or error from the validation layers except the one I specified.

Comment: @krOoze I don't understand either why I should use `VK_NULL_HANDLE` (which would make memory allocation useless as far as I understand), nor how I am supposed to use `vkGetSwapchainImagesKHR`.

Comment: Me really neither, because I am not familiar with the functionality you are using, but VUID-VkBindImageMemoryInfo-pNext-01631 requires you to do so. Though that you do not know of (the basic) `vkGetSwapchainImagesKHR` makes me suspicious if you even intended to use the advanced functionality you are using in the first place. Anyway, the `vkGetSwapchainImagesKHR(d, s, &count, nullptr)` will yield you in `count` the amount of images the swapchain contains. AFAIK it is the only way, so without calling it the layers cannot know how many there are neither (so they assume `0`).

Comment: Why do You bind memory to a swapchain Yourself? In usual scenarios, You don't need to do that.

Comment: Oh... and You enable only the default extensions (surface and swapchain), yet You use structures from some other fancy extensions (You bind memory to swapchain images). It's forbidden.

Comment: @krOoze Using `VK_NULL_HANDLE` leads to the following error sequence, and then to a segmentation fault: https://pastebin.com/raw/gucTRbZw / I've actually found mentions of `vkGetSwapchainImagesKHR` during preliminary search, but I don't understand why I'm supposed to use it since I already have two images (the color one, and the depth one). I'd only have to bind them to the swapchain, which is what I'm attempting to do. Should I stop creating my own images, and immediately call `vkGetSwapchainImagesKHR` after creating the swapchain?

Comment: @Ekzuzy That's the part I'm not understanding (about binding images to the swapchain). I don't get how the swapchain is supposed to be used if I don't bind images to it (neither do I get how the framebuffer I'm creating is supposed to be used).

Comment: If You create a swapchain, its images are create automatically. You don't create nor destroy them. Read this Intel's tutorial: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/api-without-secrets-introduction-to-vulkan-part-2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, so this is a XY problem. Seems you are using Vulkan functionality that is inappropriate for your situation. Namely `VkImageSwapchainCreateInfoKHR` and `VkBindImageMemorySwapchainInfoKHR`. Based on their descriptions they are only useful for GPU groups. But based on your comments you just want to use the Swapchain the old boring way.

Swapchain needs to create its own images in a special way. That is typically a restriction of the underlying system the Vulkan Swapchain abstracts (such as X, Wayland, GDI, or DXGI). So you would not try to create those images yourself (nor try to bind memory to them), but let `vkCreateSwapchain` do that for you.

BTW Vulkan swapchain has no use for depth image. It is all color images.

So when the Swapchain is `vkCreate`d you obtain the images it created for you with `vkGetSwapchainImagesKHR`. The usage is something like:

```
uint32_t count;
VkResult errco = vkGetSwapchainImagesKHR( dev, swpch, &count, nullptr );
if( errco ) throw "error";

std::vector<VkImage> swapchainImages( count );
errco = vkGetSwapchainImagesKHR( dev, swpch, &count, swapchainImages.data() );
if( errco ) throw "error";
```

Note: theoretically you may get more images than you asked for with `vkCreateSwapchain`.

Those images are as good as `VkImage`s obtained regularly with `vkCreateImage`, except two things:

- you are not allowed to `vkDestroyImage` them; they are instead destroyed when you call `vkDestroySwapchainKHR`.
- they already have memory bound to them (so you do not need to, nor are you allowed to bind memory to those images).

That should do for introduction, and addressing the immediate problem here.

Answer (score 0):

```
.queueFamilyIndexCount = 1
.pQueueFamilyIndices   = NULL
```

This can make segfault at vkCreateSwapchainKHR.

Comment: What’s the fix? Just remove them?

Comment: No, Just fix 1 to 0.